# How can I Store the value that is returning from async fucntion into a variable in javascript

Tags: javascript, async-await

I just wanted to get random user data from some *API* then i used async function so that at last i can return person name array.
**Here is my code**

```
const getPersonName = async () => {
  // Fake user Data api
  const response = await fetch("https://dummyjson.com/users");
  const data = await response.json();
  const firstName = data.users.map((currUser) => currUser.firstName);
  const lastName = data.users.map((currUser) => currUser.lastName);
  return [...firstName, ...lastName];
};
```

after creating the function i have to store the returning value into names variable then i tried this.

`const names = async () => await getPersonName();`

when i **console.log(names)** it is still giving me promise

*i wanted to store like this*
`const names = ['Some name','some name']`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call an async function at the top level, you can wrap your code in an async IIFE:

```
(async () => {
    const names = await getPersonName();
})();
```

Comment: Yes, but unless the environment has "top-level await" configured that code still needs to be wrapped in an async function which I think is what the OP was getting at.

Comment: if i will call the function like this then it will give me error like await cannot be used without async

Comment: Modified my answer to meet your question.